# wp_nav_menu and its fallback

Tags: theme-development, menus

When I use

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location' => 'mainnav',
    'container' => 'nav',
    'container_id' => 'mainnav',
    'container_class' => 'clearfix',
    'depth' => 4
));
```

If the user hasn't set a nav menu under Appearance menu, I notice theres a fallback like

```
<div class="menu"><ul><li class="page_item page-item-2"><a title="Sample Page" href="http://dev.klifmedia.net/ae/?page_id=2">Sample Page</a></li></ul></div>
```

How can I have the fallback use whats specified in `wp_nav_menu`? How can I check if theres a menu to display then display it, else show nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default fallback menu is created with [**wp_page_menu()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu) function and if you want to customize it the you need to create your own fallback function :

```
function my_fallback_menu(){
   $args =array('whatever');
   wp_page_menu($args);
}
```

and then call that function in your wp_nav_menu call as the fallback:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location' => 'mainnav',
    'container' => 'nav',
    'container_id' => 'mainnav',
    'container_class' => 'clearfix',
    'depth' => 4,
    'fallback_cb' => 'my_fallback_menu'
));
```

to check if a menu exists you can use `has_nav_menu()` function:

```
if (has_nav_menu( 'mainnav' )){
    //display the menu
}else{
    //no menu yet do something else
}
```

and to simplify the things even more you can just call the menu and set the fallback to false:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location' => 'mainnav',
    'container' => 'nav',
    'container_id' => 'mainnav',
    'container_class' => 'clearfix',
    'depth' => 4,
    'fallback_cb' => false
));
```